# Why I get question marks instead of text on client when I get response from server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net MVC5 in my project.

I have action method as web service:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveXml(int year, int month, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            ReadXMLReport readXml = new ReadXMLReport(file);

          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "some text in rtl language");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

As you can see method returns HttpStatusCodeResult that include some text.
The text is not english but some RTL language.

When I open the text in client I see question marks "????......?".

Any idea how to fix the problem why I get question marks instead of text?

Comment: Are you using the right [encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7)?

Comment: What does `When I open the text in client ` mean? Open how? Displayed how?

Comment: what kind of client are you opening it with? Almost certainly there's an encoding or font issue somewhere along the line.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I use Hebrow

Comment: @Michael I think rick's question was somewhat rhetorical. Ok so you're using Hebrew...but what encoding are the characters you're trying to output? Do they match? That's the point.